# Entity framework and Business layer in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, .net, entity-framework, design-patterns

I'm trying to add business layer to my simple web application.
EF generated for me classes like `User`, `Lang`

My current BL looks like this:

```
public class BLuser
    {
        public static List<User> allUsers()
        {
            using (MyEntities ctx = new MyEntities())
            {
                var users = from us in ctx.Users select us;
                return users.ToList<User>();
            }
        }


        public static int getUsersLangId(int id)
        {
            using (MyEntities ctx = new MyEntities())
            {
                var langid = (from us in ctx.Users where us.Id == id select us.Lang.Id).FirstOrDefault();
                return langid;
            }
        }

        public static void changeUsersLangId(int userId, int langId)
        {
            using (MyEntities ctx = new MyEntities())
            {
                var user = (from us in ctx.Users where us.Id == userId select us).FirstOrDefault();
                user.LangId = langId;
                ctx.SaveChanges();
            }
        }

        public static void addNewUser(int userId)
        {
            User newUser = new User();
            newUser.Id = userId;
            newUser.LangId = 0;

            using (MyEntities ctx = new MyEntities())
            {
                ctx.Users.Add(newUser);
                ctx.SaveChanges();
            }
        }

    }
```

Then in my code behind i can call it like: 
`BLuser.changeUsersLangId(1,1);`

Is it good approach (especially static methods)? I got feeling that i can miss something, but in that case i do not have to care about persistence of BL objects because of static methods.

Is there some helpful tutorial about this, what i've found are quite complicated articles not easy to understand for newbie.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Fo this case i suggest you to use `Repository Pattern`, this pattern consist an facade on your business services.

This pattern is used in this solution based on ORM

link : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/363501/Repository-pattern-with-Entity-Framework-Code-Firs

Answer (score 1):

I would inject your data access code into the business logic layer. That way it will be far easier to unit-test your business logic.

Have a look at the [Dependency Injection](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html) pattern.

Your data access code should return objects, have a look at the [Repository pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html).

If you have specific questions about these articles I'm sure SO users can help.

In general, static methods are never a good idea because they lead to inflexible code that is difficult to unit-test.